# Rails: Active Admin Association Image column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I am new to ruby on rails and have just installed active admin and was trying to customize the

views.

I have a product and image table. Each image belongs to one product.

Now I want to display a column with the associated image when showing the products page.

At the moment it´s only the image_url text which isn´t working. Later on I would like do

have the picture displayed in 50x50px.

How to I do this? (image model: name:string image_url:text)

Here is what I have done :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do

index do
    column "Image" do |image|
        image.image_url
    end
    column :name
    column :preview_text
    column :full_text
    column :price, :sortable => :price do |product|
      div :class => "price" do
          number_to_currency product.price
     end
    end
 default_actions
 end
end
```

I dont know how to fix that part with " do image. I am a beginner in rails 2 days exp..

It seems the syntax is wrong and throwing error:

```
undefined method `image_url' for #<Product:0x00000101b5a458>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to get the `image_url` from the image object `product.image.image_url`.

Regarding the image size, you can display the image with the size you want, like so

```
column "Image" do |product|
  image_tag product.image.image_url, class: 'my_image_size'
end
```

.css

```
.my_image_size {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Or you can actually resize the image itself, with a gem such as [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave).

Comment: or you can just do `image_tag product.image.image_url, size: "50x50"` without needing to deal with css.

Answer (score 1):

```
column "Image" do |product|
  image_tag (product.image,width:100,height:80) 
end


references
image=it's belongs to your database column name
product=it creates new object for your image by activeadmin register class method.
```

Comment: You should add some explanations. It is always appreciated... ;)